# how to import a module in Yang

Tags: import, ietf-netmod-yang

I'm trying to build a CLI. I choose to use 'yang' to do so. I'm new to it and can't find out how to import existing moduls. As exemple I found a module for ospf on github (https://github.com/YangModels/yang/blob/master/vendor/cisco/xe/1631/ietf-ospf.yang) and I would like to import it in my own moduls. Can this be done? how?

EDIT1:

```
module mininet {

 /* name space */
 namespace "http://tail-f.com/ns/example/mininet";
 prefix mininet;

 import ietf-ospf {
     prefix ospf;
     revision-date 2015-03-09
 }

 leaf area-id-type {
     type yang:area-id-type;
 }
}
```

So I tried to do it this way using Piotr Babij help. Unfortunately this isn't working. What do I need to change?
area-id-type is a typedef of ietf-ospf. The error I have is te following one:

```
mininet.yang:12:3: error: trailing garbage after module
mininet.yang:12:3: error: unterminated statement
```

Comment: `What do I need to change?` Well, you are missing a semicolon (`;`) for the `revision-date` statement. The parser of the tool you are using got confused a bit because of it, giving you those non descriptive error messages. Plus, you are still using the wrong `prefix` for the type reference from the imported module.

Answer (score 4):

You may import other modules in your own modules by using the `import` statement. It is described in both [RFC 7950](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7950#section-7.1.5) for YANG 1.1 and in [RFC 6020](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6020#section-7.1.5) for YANG 1.0. In YANG 1.1 you may import two different revisions of the same module. Other that that, the `import` statement works the same in both versions.

In practice the basic import looks like this:

```
 module acme-system {
     namespace "http://acme.example.com/system";
     prefix "acme";

     import ietf-yang-types {
         prefix "yang";
         revision-date 2013-07-15;
     }

     leaf acme-ip-address {
         type yang:dotted-quad;
     }
 }
```

If you omit the optional `revision-date` statement then an undefined module revision is imported. So, in general, it is a good practive to use it.

The mandatory `prefix` statement lets you to refer to the things in the imported module. In the example the prefix of the imported `ietf-yang-types` module is `yang` and, thanks to that, it is clear that `yang:dotted-quad` refers to a type from that module. In your case you have set the prefix to `ospf`, so you should have `ospf:area-id-type` to refer to a type definition from that module. If you import multiple modules you need to ensure their prefixes are unique.

Additionally, you are importing the oldest available revision of the `ietf-ospf` module. I just hope that this is what you really want to do.

Anyway, once you import a module you are allowed to:

> - use any `grouping` and `typedef` defined at the top level in the imported module or its submodules.
> - use any `extension`, `feature`, and `identity` defined in the imported module or its submodules.
> - use any node in the imported module's schema tree in `must`, `path`, and `when` statements, or as the target node in `augment` and `deviation` statements.

In the above example the `typedef dotted-quad` from the `ietf-yang-types` is used in the `acme-system` module.

Comment: thanks for your help but it isn't working, I'm edditing the original post.

Comment: I updated the answer. You should use prefix to refer to the stuff in the imported module.